# Time series of NDVI calculation from Sentinal in earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth

I am new in google earth engine, i am trying to plot the time series NDVI value and images as well, i found a script and i tried to modified but its not working properly. Below is the code

its giving error that, `Error generating chart: The image collection is empty`.

I just changed here the var geometry, and i imported the KML file using fusion table and paste the link here. How to display the statistics graph and images also for selected region

```
//Import GEE Feature Collection (My AOI kml)
    var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:19HmlYA6D2W-soGuCJGOvdEutyTNdZFK1tUFz2JAM');

// Create image collection of S-2 imagery for the perdiod 2016-2019
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')

//filter start and end date
.filterDate('2016-02-01', '2019-02-28')

//filter according to drawn boundary
.filterBounds(geometry);

// Function to mask cloud from built-in quality band
// information on cloud
var maskcloud1 = function(image) {
var QA60 = image.select(['QA60']);
return image.updateMask(QA60.lt(1));
};

// Function to calculate and add an NDVI band
var addNDVI = function(image) {
return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']));
};

// Add NDVI band to image collection
var S2 = S2.map(addNDVI);
// Extract NDVI band and create NDVI median composite image
var NDVI = S2.select(['nd']);
var NDVImed = NDVI.median(); //I just changed the name of this variable ;)

// Create palettes for display of NDVI
var ndvi_pal = ['#d73027', '#f46d43', '#fdae61', '#fee08b', '#d9ef8b',
'#a6d96a'];

// Create a time series chart.
var plotNDVI = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(S2, geometry,ee.Reducer.mean(),
'nd',500,'system:time_start', 'system:index')
              .setChartType('LineChart').setOptions({
                title: 'NDVI short-term time series',
                hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
                vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'}
});

// Display.
print(plotNDVI);

// Display NDVI results on map
Map.addLayer(NDVImed.clip(geometry), {min:-0.5, max:0.9, palette: ndvi_pal}, 'NDVI');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geometry of your asset is inside the property 'geometry'. you have to tell the Earth Engine to get the geometry from that property using the argument 'column'.

```
//Import GEE Feature Collection (My AOI kml)
var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:19HmlYA6D2W-soGuCJGOvdEutyTNdZFK1tUFz2JAM', 'geometry');
```

However, reducing over such a large region will probably run into memory issues. So consider using smaller regions of interest or a larger scale. Eventually export the results.

Then it should work: [link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6609d6f2a2f09d9ef162e82390b5f385)